# Website not centered

Tags: html, css

i am sorry for this question but i did everything right and i dont know whats wrong
currently my css is

```
body{
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
width:986px;
 border:0;
 font-size:100%;
 font:inherit;
 vertical-align:middle;
 }
```

this is supposed to center the page and yea it worked in alot of website
but in this website something is wrong
on my monitor its centered but on other people's montiors its not..
my resoultion is 1440x900

and here is the website link so you check out the whole css
http://musikschule-landau.de/

I am not using bootstrap this is just for font-awesome for social media links
I hope someone can help me please,
Regards

Comment: Sorry about the formatting in my comment. Bootstrap isn't necessary for fontawesome to function.

Comment: Just remove `width: 986px;` from the `body` and also remove the inline `margin-left` properties form the elements

Comment: I see a couple of mistakes there... :|

Comment: @HashemQolami what are the mistakes and can u help me fix them please?

Comment: @HashemQolami if i remove the marign-left and the width 986px website goes crazy ahhahaha

Comment: I use this base code of body in alot of website but its the first time for this to happen and i dont know why

Comment: First of all you shouldn't position the elements by `margin` property, remove all the inline `margin-left` as I mentioned (including the applied width to `body`)

Comment: @HashemQolami i used margin property in alot of website and it worked well but if i shouldnt position using margin property how can i position all of those elements

Comment: Second, considering the usage of TW bootstrap the container should have a class of `container` instead of an ID of `container`

Comment: Thanks i found the problem had to delete that bootstrap link to css

Comment: @user3920142 Specifying an explicit margin makes the elements position relative to the left side of their parent (in this case, body). Hence in different monitors with different sizes, it causes a trouble

Comment: Now that you've fixed the problem of your css getting overridden, may I suggest migrating your inline styles to your external css for ease of maintenance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that bootstrap is overwriting your styles. Try to load `style.css` after bootstrap. Then you should remove inline style `style="margin-left:200px;"` from elements where yoy have added it manualy, then I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin: 0 auto` from body styles. Then remove all `margin-left: 200px` (dor example in `#cssmenu`).

Here we go!